# Loop a map and multiply value by lets say 20 in Java8

Tags: java, java-8

How to loop a map elements and multiply value by lets say number 20 in java8 and get result?

I don't want to loop in usual for loop i want to make it efficient.

Comment: why do you think a classic loop isn't efficient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently iterate over each entry in a 'Map'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` if you want to mutate the map itself:

```
myMap.replaceAll((k, v) -> v * 20);
```

or collect to a new map:

```
myMap.entrySet()
     .stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue() * 20));
```